# is there a command to see all the branches created from or merged with a specific branch?

Tags: git, version-control, branching-and-merging

Is there a command to see all the branches created from or merged with a specific branch? Basically, we have branch AA which was used to create some other branches and branch AA was updated after. I would like to make sure all the branches that used branch AA are updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Git doesn't keep track of where a branch came from or what commit was tied to what branch.  You can look at the log and make a guess what branch that it came from, but there is no way to guarantee that it came from that branch.

If you made a commit that you want to make sure all your branches have, you can cross reference the results of `git branch --contains shaOfCommit` with `git branch`